# "Error: expression must have class type" on reference to member of ref struct C++/CLI

Tags: .net, struct, c++-cli

I have searched through the posts on this website and although there are several others who have the same error message, they don't seem to apply to the issue I am having.

I am using C++/CLI with the .NET framework in visual studio 2013 Community Edition. I have defined a `ref` `struct` within a header file, `Point.h`, which I then created an instance of within the header file of a windows form, `MainForm.h`. (There is no `#include` statement for `Point.h` within `MainForm.h` because it is included in `FractalScript.h`, which is included in `MainForm.h`

whenever I attempt to access any of the member variables for that instance of the `struct`, I get the error mentioned in the title. I won't post my entire source code because some of it is completely separate from and irrelevant to this issue. If you want to see my entire source code however, I can post it.

`Main.cpp`

```
 #include "MainForm.h"

 int main()
 {
     FractalGenerator::MainForm m;
     m.ShowDialog();

     return 0;
 }
```

`Point.h`

```
 namespace point
 {
     ref struct Config
     {
         //float width is the width in pixels of the shape
         float width;

         //float height is the height in pixels of the shape
         float height;

         //float x is the x coordinate in pixels of the top-left corner of  the shape
         float x;

         //float y is the y coordinate in pixels of the top-left corner of the shape
         float y;

         //int argb_a is the alpha channel of the colour of the shape (value between 0 and 255)
         int argb_a;

         //int argb_r is the red channel of the colour of the shape (value between 0 and 255)
         int argb_r;

         //int argb_g is the green channel of the colour of the shape (value between 0 and 255)
    int argb_g;

         //int argb_b is the blue channel of the colour of the shape (value between 0 and 255)
         int argb_b;
     };
 }
```

`MainForm.h`

```
 #include "FractalScript.h"
 #using <System.Windows.Forms.dll>

 #pragma once

 namespace FractalGenerator {

     using namespace System;
     using namespace System::ComponentModel;
     using namespace System::Collections;
     using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
     using namespace System::Data;
     using namespace System::Drawing;

 public ref class MainForm : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
     {
     public:
         MainForm(void)
         {
             InitializeComponent();
         }

 public:
         void FillRectangleFloat(point::Config^ pConf, bool colour, PaintEventArgs^ e)
         {
             if (colour)
             {
                 SolidBrush^ brush = gcnew SolidBrush(Color::FromArgb(255, 0, 0, 0));
                 e->Graphics->FillRectangle(brush, pConf.x, pConf.y, pConf.width, pConf.height);
             }
             else
             {
                 SolidBrush^ brush = gcnew SolidBrush(Color::White);
                 e->Graphics->FillRectangle(brush, pConf.x, pConf.y, pConf.width, pConf.height);
             }
         }

         point::Config^ pConf{};

           //After this is just a few other variable/function declarations,
           //the windows form designer auto generated code, and some event handlers
           //which are not relevant to the issue
 };
 }
```

The error is occurring in lines 29 and 34 of `MainForm.h` when I try to reference the members of `pConf` which is declared on line 38. The same error also occurs in a different place where I try to assign values to the members. (and yes, the assignment of values does happen before I call the function shown where I try to reference the values)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    e->Graphics->FillRectangle(brush, pConf.x, pConf.y, pConf.width, pConf.height);
```

It is simple syntax mistake, Config is a reference type and pConf is a reference to a Config object so you must use `->` to dereference members.  The ^ hat on the pConf declaration is your cue.

Don't be confused by `ref struct`, it is not a `value struct` and thus not a value type where you'd use `.` to dereference members.  It is simply a syntactical equivalent of a class with all members having public accessibility by default.   Clumsiness that was inspired by the way native C++ treats struct vs class.  Best avoided, limit yourself to either `ref class` or `value struct`.

You *might* have intended to declare Config to be a value type, it does fit the pattern.  Not recommended however, value types should not have more than 4 simple fields.  Bigger ones are inefficient and get expensive to copy and pass by value to or return from functions.  The sweet spot for value types is their ability to fit in available CPU registers.

Fix:

```
    e->Graphics->FillRectangle(brush, pConf->x, pConf->y, pConf->width, pConf->height);
```